# update ranking in parent child based data

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table where `user_id` and `parent_user_id` is stored. For example:

```
user_id    parent_user_id   calls      designation
---------------------------------------------------
1          0                 10        Tech Support
2          1                 5         Sr. Tech Support
3          2                 11        Tech Support
4          2                 12        Tech Support
5          4                 10        Tech Support
```

Scenario is, if a user who has 2 children with 10 calls each, he will get an designation change like Sr. Tech Support. And If he has 10 such callers, it will be Manager.

To do this so far what I have done(java),

```
@Override
public boolean updateDesignation(int userId, int depth) {
    // check whether maximum depth is reached
    if (depth == 0)
        return false;
    depth--;

    int userIds = getIds(userId);//Will get parent_id

    String LOCAL_SQL = SQLconstants.getSQL("get-total-calls.sql");

    if(userIds>0) {
        int calls = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(LOCAL_SQL, Integer.class, userIds);
            // I get 4's calls with which I need to see if I have 2 users with 10 calls each!
        updateDesignation(userIds, depth);
    }
    //updateRanks(userId, depth);       
    return true;
}
```

If I pass 5 as user_id, and 4 as depth. It will go till user_id and update values. And how it works is `5->4, 4->2, 2->1`. But what I need to achieve is `5->4`, and check 4's child's calls. same like `3, 2, 1`. How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(userIds>=0) {    // process 0 too, as it is a parent 
    /* execute this sql
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE parent_user_id=userIds AND calls>=10;
       then check if the returned value is >= 2 or other chekings...
       and update designations..
    */
    updateDesignation(userIds, depth);
}
```

In this way u dont need to get calls of each parent. So this line is not needed anymore:

`int calls = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(LOCAL_SQL, Integer.class, userIds);`

Comment: In this case, like 1 -> (parent of 1)2 -> 3(parent of 3). How I need to check? Bcoz we need to process all users

Comment: With the `COUNT` query u get the total no of children of a parent having calls>10. check if this value >= 2.
Then u can get all the users under this parent with a query like-
`SELECT user_id from tablename WHERE parent_user_id=userIds;`
and using a loop u can update them. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: My problem is, if a user has 2 tech support with >10 calls, he is sr. tech, and if a user with 2 sr.teh support under him will become manager. How to do this logic? That was my original problem